# Regex validation with Prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, validation

I want to validate a form fields (text) input. It should only be a number between 5 and 10. I know there is the validate-number class, but this does not check the numbe range. Is there some way to do that with Prototype?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found this validation script based on prototype. A number-range is also supported.
[prototype validation script](http://tetlaw.id.au/view/javascript/really-easy-field-validation)